# Does This Game Effect Every Number?

Tags: solution-verification, infinity

I made a game while at home, and I couldn't solve it for 3 months. The question is below, and the proof is below it. Please let me know if you see any problems!

[image: The question]
You start with the equation shown to the above, with a=0 and ± being in the plus state and n being -1. You would then solve the equation. The numbers would vary depending on n, but it would be 1, 5, 21, 85, and so on. You would then make that number be equal to a3±1. So for 5, a would be 2, and the ± would be in the minus state. We can say that for any odd number (z) (This doesn’t work with even numbers.) that a=z∓1/3. You would play starting at n=-1 for each number, and end at n=∞ so the numbers the game “effects” infinite numbers for every number you play with. You would then plug in the answer for each time you change n as “z”. The question is, starting with a=0 and ± being in the plus state and n being -1, can you eventually get every odd number?

[image: The proof part 1]

[image: The proof part 2]

[image: The proof part 3]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This question as formulated is likely to be closed. It's complex, all you show are pictures, and you don't ask about any specific point. You are asking a lot of any potential reader.

Comment: There's some serious problems with your post. First, [your title should be your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144). Second, your question should be [visible and searchable](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992); don't force your readers to click on external links just to see what you are asking.

Comment: I'm working on fixing the question per your recommendations. I am new to Stackexchange, I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: The usual way to communicate with the users is not per e-mail, but directly in the site (Perhaps per chat) . Every user should be able to benefit from results.

Comment: Use Latex for formula and numbers. However, read [Mathematics Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/) before to continue to post in wrong way.

Comment: Hi OP! I still find your question a bit hard to understand. As I understand it, you've devised some sort of game where you create a sequence of numbers according to some rules, and you want to know if you could reach any odd number. I appreciate that it probably seems obvious to you, but can you try to explain a little more what the rules you have to obey are? Your "equation" (which I would technically call a formula) is a little hard to understand. What does $a3$ mean? Is this a variables, $a \cdot 3$, or the concatenation of $a$ and $3$? What changes are you allowed to make? ...

Comment: Perhaps you could explicitly show yourself "playing" the game, explaining what you do at each step in detail. I think this would help me to understand it a lot. From my first glance at your proof, its a little bit hard to read also. It's presented in an unfamiliar way, I guess. Can you clarify if your proof relies on the deduction that if you have a sequence of infinitely many distinct numbers, every number must eventually be reached? I'm also a bit unclear about the step where you say "we see that [some sequence] has exponential growth". How do you see this?